# Убрать дубли из результата запроса

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
SELECT cp.phone, cm.email, client.id  
FROM client  
LEFT JOIN client_phones cp ON cp.client_id = client.id  
LEFT JOIN client_emails cm ON cm.client_id = client.id
```

у клиента есть несколько телефонов и email.
после такого запроса получаются дубли, что-то типа CROSS JOIN
как устранить дубликаты? в таблицах `client_phones, client_emails` нет уникального id записи, но есть delta (инкримент для конкретного клиента)

текущий результат получается такой:

```
phone              mail        id
8-000-0000-00   one@yandex.ru   1
8-000-0000-00   two@yandex.ru   1
8-000-0000-01   one@yandex.ru   1
8-000-0000-01   two@yandex.ru   1
+70000          test@list.ru    2
```

тк для id = 1, создано по 2 мыла и телефона

Comment: А на пальцах сможете объяснить, что нужно? Хотя бы пример (один клиент, два телефона и email)

Comment: обновил вопрос

Comment: Тоже интересует этот вопрос.
Дубли реально есть. Если в таблице users 1 юзер и в таблице email у него 5 емайлов, то выводится так:

юзер - емайл
юзер - емайл
юзер - емайл
юзер - емайл
юзер - емайл

а должно быть так:

юзер - емайл
емайл
емайл
емайл
емайл

Comment: ModaL, можете заюзать group_concat()  http://blog.nagaychenko.com/2010/06/15/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-group_concat/

Comment: У Вас та же проблема. Именно при объединении дубли. В базе их нет.

Comment: а distinct разве не должен помочь?

Comment: @ModaL, как раз-таки должно быть "юзер - емайл юзер - емайл юзер - емайл юзер - емайл юзер - емайл".

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT client.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT concat(cp.phone, cm.email) SEPARATOR "|") as phone_and_mail
FROM client  
LEFT JOIN client_phones cp ON cp.client_id = client.id  
LEFT JOIN client_emails cm ON cm.client_id = client.id
GROUP BY client.id
```

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

Так:

```sql
SELECT client.id, 'phone' as info_type, cp.phone as info
FROM client  
  JOIN client_phones cp ON cp.client_id = client.id  
UNION ALL
SELECT client.id, 'email', cm.email
FROM client
  JOIN client_emails cm ON cm.client_id = client.id
```